# API for "Add to Google Wallet" equivalent to PayButton

Tags: android, google-pay, google-wallet

Can't seem to find an equivalent `PayButton` for "Add to wallet" scenario. [ButtonOptions](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#ButtonOptions) for the `PayButton` don't have an `ADD` option. Any idea if there's an API for it rather than managing assets for it?

Comment: What objects (boarding passes, gift cards) would you like to add to Google Wallet?

Comment: @Domi it's a provisioned payment card

Comment: So this would be about payment card push provisioning. Correct?

Comment: Not the provisioning itself - I'm simply wondering if there is a similar component to `PayButton`, let's call it `WalletButton`, that perhaps yes, would trigger the flow for provisioning.

Comment: The `PayButton` is meant for payment flows. Triggering the provisioning flow would mean that you need to be an issuer. Checkout https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android (you might need to request access) for implementing a payment card provisioning flow.